# Softlayer: determine scsi disk Softlayer-ID using the dev mapper device id

Tags: centos7, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, lvm, iscsi, device-mapper

In a setup of a multiple `iscsi` disks attached to a Linux host (LVM pools setup), I want to be able to take a snapshot of a specific disk, using `Softlayer API`.
How can I know the id or the LUN name of the iscsi device from the Linux device name.

For example - get `"SLXXXXXXXXX-XX"` from `"/dev/mapper/YYYYYYYYYYYYYYp1"`.

I tried resolving the Iscsi target Ip, but it's possible that different disks have same target ip, so I have to figure out a different solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using these REST requests you can retrieve the ISCSI id, and LUN id of the device and its parent for those BMS and Virtual Guests that have any.

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests.json?objectMask=mask[allowedNetworkStorage[lunId,parentVolume[lunId]]]&objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"allowedNetworkStorage":{"nasType":{"operation":"ISCSI"}}}}
```

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware.json?objectMask=mask[allowedNetworkStorage[lunId,parentVolume[lunId]]]&objectFilter={"hardware":{"allowedNetworkStorage":{"nasType":{"operation":"ISCSI"}}}}
```

Method: GET

This link might help you for further implementation:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi

Comment: The "lunId" info solves my problem as it is a unique identifier for a scsi volume, that is visible by the OS. Thanks!